# Run an existing project in Xampp

Tags: symfony, xampp

I have an existing project created in Symfony. I'd lke to make some changes on it but first of all I need to make it run on my localhost.... I already downloaded Xampp on my Mac Mojave and Start it and the I went to /opt/lampp and explore the drive and paste the folder that contains the files.

I already installed Composer and Symfony using Xampp Terminals.... I have no idea what else I need to do to run it on the localhost. When I try to go to the project folder using http://localhost:8000/quizair it has an error 403.

If anyone has step by step to do it. I appreciate

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

did if you use http://localhost:8000/quizair it means you using symfony server?
if you want to use this link, use should do `composer require --dev symfony/web-server-bundle` in your file project

if you want to use apache server, i dont know how in your pc, but in my laptop, i'm using
https://localhost/myproject/public/

hope my answer can help you

Comment: it didn't work. What other software can I use to run this symfony project? I really don't know how to start it... I really appreciate if you can teach me. I already google and try so many things...Thanks

Comment: @CesarIvanArdilaVega i'm using phpstorm to open project my symfony. i'm using `https://rojas.io/creating-a-website-with-symfony-4-part-1/` and `https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html#gsc.tab=0` as my reference, rojas.io is good tutorial for me.